# How to get the element-wise mean across blocks of same dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, mean

I would like to compute the element-wise means across multiple blocks of the same dataframe. My `input` table looks like this, and it consists of 3 (3x3) blocks, with each block having a diagonal of ones:

```
input = data.frame(
  var1 = c(1,7,4,1,2,9,1,8,3),
  var2 = c(3,1,9,4,1,8,3,1,8),
  var3 = c(3,9,1,6,8,1,3,5,1) )
```

The `output` table should be a 3x3 including the means of the elements which are located on similar positions in their blocks. E.g. the first row of the `output` table should be `c(1, 3.3, 4)`. Any idea how to smartly code this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(input, 1:3), colMeans))

      var1     var2     var3
1 1.000000 3.333333 4.000000
2 5.666667 1.000000 7.333333
3 5.333333 8.333333 1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tapply` or even `aggregate`

```
tapply(unlist(input), list((row(input)-1)%%3,col(input)), mean)

         1        2        3
0 1.000000 3.333333 4.000000
1 5.666667 1.000000 7.333333
2 5.333333 8.333333 1.000000

aggregate(.~id, cbind(id=rep(1:3,3),input),mean)
  id     var1     var2     var3
1  1 1.000000 3.333333 4.000000
2  2 5.666667 1.000000 7.333333
3  3 5.333333 8.333333 1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If each of the blocks are of the same dimension, then we can also use `array` route

```
t(apply(array(as.matrix(input), c(3, 3, 3)), 1, colMeans))
```

-output

```
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1.000000 3.333333 4.000000
[2,] 5.666667 1.000000 7.333333
[3,] 5.333333 8.333333 1.000000
```